# How can I use Nanopore reads to close gaps or resolve repeats in a short-read assembly?

Tags: nanopore, long-reads, repeat-elements, scaffold

Low coverage MinION reads should be useful to close gaps and resolve repeats left by short-read assemblers. However, I haven't had any success with the software I know about. I'm aware of the following packages, either for scaffolding or closing gaps in short-read assemblies using long reads:

- [`LINKS`](https://github.com/warrenlr/LINKS/)
- [`OPERA-LG`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/operasf)
- [`npScarf`](https://github.com/mdcao/npScarf)
- [`PBJelly`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pb-jelly)
- [`SSPACE-longread`](https://www.baseclear.com/genomics/bioinformatics/basetools/SSPACE-longread)

I've tried `npScarf` and `LINKS`, and they ran successfully but didn't resolve the gaps in my assembly. I couldn't get `PBJelly` and `OPERA-LG` to run with the current versions of `BLASR` and `samtools`, and both packages seem not to be maintained. I have not tried `SSPACE-longread` because it's not open source.

**What software can I use to fill gaps and resolve repeats in a short-read assembly with low-coverage Nanopore data?**

---

#### More information

I'm finishing a mitochondrial genome. I have a 17 kb short read assembly with one gap. This was made from 2x150b paired-end reads from a TruSeq PCR-free library with a 400 b insert size. Molecular data suggests the genome may be around 32 kb.

After mapping short reads against the short read assembly, `Pilon` identified a tandem repeat of 156 bp in an AT-rich region, but wasn't able to close the gap.

I have 1.4 Gb of MinION rapid reads with an L50 of 8808 b. I mapped these reads against the short read assembly, and I can see reads that span the gap. I seem to have the information required to close the gap, but I don't know how to do it.

The organism has a nuclear genome > 600 Mb, so long read coverage is low. Despite this, I tried a *de novo* `Canu` assembly of the Nanopore reads, and I pulled out a 39 kb contig containing mitochondrial genes. Most genes on this contig are duplicated and fragmented, and `Pilon` wasn't able to improve it.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to look into [Unicycler](https://github.com/rrwick/Unicycler) (manuscript with more information [can be found here](http://journals.plos.org/ploscompbiol/article?id=10.1371/journal.pcbi.1005595)); even though it is supposed to be used with bacterial genomes only, it might work well with a small genome such as a mitochondrion's.

[image]

Beware that if you happen to have very long reads, you might end up with an assembly with multiple copies of the circular genome: you might want to look into [circlator](https://github.com/sanger-pathogens/circlator) then.

Comment: Mitochondria **are** bacteria. Their long co-evolution as endosymbiotes may have had an influence in some of their genomic characteristics, though.

Comment: Exactly; in fact, I'm not aware of any bacteria with a ~32kb genome :)

Comment: This worked well for me. I got a single 21 kb circular contig with all the expected mt genes. Thanks for alerting me to this software!